# Issue with insert query in sqlite? (Values are not inserted)

Tags: javascript, cordova, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to Sqlite, I am unable to insert values in DB, by the following code both database and tables are created but the values are no inserted, What is wrong with my code? Any suggestions!!! I am able to see the alert values are stored but not able to see in table data.

```
     $("#btnDefaultSave").click(function(){
              var Latlongs = "Test1";
              var Location = "Test2";
              var Category = "Test3";
              var Address = "Test4";
              var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "TestDB"});
              db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Locationlog (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Coordinates TEXT, Location TEXT, Category TEXT, Address TEXT)');
          });
     db.transaction(function (tx){
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES ('+Latlongs+', '+Location+', '+Category+', '+Address+')');
                                                                        alert("values are stored");
                                                                        });

                                                        });
```

Comment: Id is not inserting you have to keep auto generate in that..
you have given primary key,,, but not auto increment in that.
search for that in create time of table you have to do that

Comment: use AUTOINCREMENT in your create table query,,, like
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Locationlog (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , Coordinates TEXT, Location TEXT, Category TEXT, Address TEXT)');

Comment: Will try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: I tried the same, It does't work..

Comment: user3300593, did you drop table before trying the idea with autoincrement? It will also be better to execute both SQL statements in one transaction

Comment: NO it is not working, Can you please show me one example with auto increment table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the format of insert query as follows,

```
     db.transaction(function (tx){

  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[Latlongs,Location,Category,Address]);
   alert("values are stored");
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when "values are stored" message is shown, the "insert .." SQL statement might still being executed. Please check if the db transaction is done in a success callback.

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
       tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Locationlog (Coordinates, Location, Category, Address) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[Latlongs,Location,Category,Address]);
    }, function successCB() {
       alert("values are stored!");
    }, function errorCB() {
       alert("Error!");
    }
);
```